# How to split, substring and sort strings between segues so it appears correctly in my table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a list of elements that are in the format of:

```
let myTableData : [String] = [
    "var/lib/file1.txt",
    "var/lib/file2.txt",
    "home/user/Documents",
    "home/user/text.txt",
    "usr/bin/bash",
    "usr/bin/sh"
]
```

In my viewcontroller I have a table where a would present the data simillar the way a file explorer does. So initially the table should only contain and display the following rows:

```
var
home
usr
```

So when the user press `var`, a segue is being triggered and the same viewcontroller will display the data under `var`, that is
`lib`, and when the user press `lib` a segue is being triggered and the table will then contain:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Actually the segue navigation works just fine. It is just that when the user press, let´s say `usr`, then the `lib` is not displayes in the table but all the lines in `myTableData.

Below is the code I have written so far. Have a look at the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` function where I sort the data that should be displayed when the segue is triggered.

I am not sure how to proceed to get it in the way I want. Any ideas?

Below is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let myTableData : [String] = [
        "var/lib/file1.txt",
        "var/lib/file2.txt",
        "home/user/Documents",
        "home/user/text.txt",
        "usr/bin/bash",
        "usr/bin/sh"
    ]
    var currentObjects : [String] = []
    var splitRegex: String = "/"
    var currentPath: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        currentObjects.removeAll()

        for name in myTableData {
            // First split the string
            let keysArr = name.components(separatedBy: splitRegex)
            // Then set currentPath to the first element of the splitted string (e.g. var or home or var/lib etc
            currentPath = keysArr[0]
            // Check if name contains the part 
            // (e.g. check if "usr/lib/file1.txt" contains "usr"
            if name.contains(currentPath) {

                let index = name.index(currentPath.startIndex, offsetBy: currentPath.characters.count)
                // Split, e.g split "var" out from var/lib/file.txt
                currentPath = name.substring(to: index)

                // Check if currentObjects contains currentPath
                if !currentObjects.contains(currentPath) {
                    currentObjects.append(currentPath)
                }
            }
        }
        return currentObjects.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        // Get current strings/paths from currentObjects
        let text = currentObjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = text

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: "select")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {

            if let cell = sender as? String {
                destination.splitRegex = currentPath
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the structure:

[image]

**EDIT**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        currentPath.removeLast()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend putting your data into Types rather than strings. That should get your most of the way.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You declared your variables **inside** the ViewController, so every ViewController will start with its own data. In my solution I used the laziest approach (***don't do that in a real app!***), you should look into better ways to *handle data between view controllers*.
2. Don't create a new cell every time, instead **prefetch** cells using storyboards
3. You don't need to fire segues manually, they are already being managed by storyboard.
4. Finally, here's the working code; I'll leave you (as an exercise) how to correctly manage the backward navigation.

   ```
   import UIKit


   let myTableData : [String] = [
       "var/lib/file1.txt",
       "var/lib/file2.txt",
       "home/user/Documents",
       "home/user/text.txt",
       "usr/bin/bash",
       "usr/bin/sh"
   ]

   var currentObjects : [String] = []
   var splitRegex: String = "/"
   var currentPath = [String]()

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

       @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           self.tableView.dataSource = self
           self.tableView.delegate = self
       }

       func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           return 1
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

           currentObjects.removeAll()

           for name in myTableData {

               let keysArr = name.components(separatedBy: splitRegex)

               if currentPath.count == 0 || keysArr[currentPath.count - 1] == currentPath.last {

                   if !currentObjects.contains(keysArr[currentPath.count]) {
                       currentObjects.append(keysArr[currentPath.count])
                   }
               }

           }

           return currentObjects.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
           let text = currentObjects[indexPath.row]
           cell.textLabel?.text = text

           return cell
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           currentPath.append(currentObjects[indexPath.row])
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess the simpliest approach is to keep track of what elements that was stored in `currentPath` when navigating back to the previous viewcontroller? Or is there any more effective way? And the best way to handle data between viewcontrollers should be to store them in a singleton class I guess.

Comment: Please, look at my edit above. That was the lines I added to get it working so I can navigate back and forward. Is that the best solution according to you?